# Problema con el salto de una línea de código al usar Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Cuando intento ejecutar el código de abajo no obtengo ningún error de compilación, pero cuando se ejecuta el código, parece que se salta la línea de código de la clase `Scanner`. El error se encuentra en el método `AddStudentInfo()`.

```
 package com.nerviosus;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String birthdate;
    private int grade;
    private String address;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String parentPhoneNumber;
    private double math;
    private double english;
    private double history;
    private double spanish;
    private double chemistry;
    private double physics;
    private String optional1;
    private String optional2;
    private double option1;
    private double option2;


    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    public void optionalSubject (){
        System.out.println("Introduce the first optional subject");
        String optionalSubject1 = scanner.nextLine();
        this.optional1 = optionalSubject1;
        System.out.println("Introduce the second optional subject");
        String optionalSubject2 = scanner.nextLine();
        this.optional2 = optionalSubject2;

    }

    public double introduceMarks (){
        double math, english, history, chemistry, physics, spanish;
        double option1, option2;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in Mathematics: ");
        math = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.math = math;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in English: ");
        english = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.english = english;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in History: ");
        history = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.history = history;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in Chemistry: ");
        chemistry = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in Physics: ");
        physics = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.physics = physics;
        System.out.println("Introduce your mark in Spanish: ");
        spanish = scanner.nextDouble();
        this.spanish = spanish;
        if ((optional1 != null) && (optional2 != null)) {
            System.out.println("Introduce your mark in " + optional1);
            option1 = scanner.nextDouble();
            this.option1 = option1;
            System.out.println("Introduce your mark in " + optional2);
            option2 = scanner.nextDouble();
            this.option2 = option2;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error, please introduce your optional subjects");
        }



        return math + english + history + chemistry + physics + spanish;
    }

    public void markAverage (){
        System.out.println("Your average is: " + (this.chemistry + this.spanish + this.physics + this.history + this.english
                + this.math + this.option1 + this.option2)/8);
    }

    public void addStudentInfo (){
        System.out.println("Enter student's name: ");
        this.name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter student's birth date: ");
        this.birthdate = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter student's grade: ");
        this.grade = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter student's phone number: ");
        this.phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter parent phone number: ");
        this.parentPhoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter email address: ");
        this.emailAddress = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter address: ");
        this.address = scanner.nextLine();

    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return "Street address: "+address;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return "Email address: " +emailAddress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return "Phone number: "+phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getParentPhoneNumber() {
        return "Parent phone number: "+parentPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void getAllData (){
        System.out.println(getName());
        System.out.println(getBirthdate());
        System.out.println(getGrade());
        if (getEmailAddress().equals("")){

        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getEmailAddress());
        }
        if (getAddress().equals("")){

        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getAddress());
        }
        if (getParentPhoneNumber().equals("")){

        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getParentPhoneNumber());
        }
        if (getPhoneNumber().equals("")){

        }
        else {
            System.out.println(getPhoneNumber());
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Name: " + name;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return "Birth date: " + birthdate;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return "Current grade: " + grade;
    }
}
```

Siento no poder describir mejor el problema: Este es el error:

[image: Este es el error de scanner]

Comment: por favor incluye la parte en la que defines las variables a las que les asignas el valor que recibe el Scanner.

Comment: Añade el codigo completo para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explicación

Primero que todo, no ha ocurrido ningún error, lo que sucedió es debido al funcionamiento de algunos métodos de la clase `Scanner`.

El problema radica en que el método `Scanner.nextInt()` no consume el último carácter de salto de línea que se ingresó (al oprimir la tecla Enter después de ingresar el student's grade, genera un carácterer que representa un salto de línea y que no es consumido por el scanner) y, por lo tanto, ese salto de línea es consumido en la siguiente llamada al método `Scanner.nextLine()`. Es por eso que se salta esa línea de código.

Este mismo problema ocurre cuando se usa el método `Scanner.nextLine()` después de `Scanner.next()` o cualquier otro `Scanner.next...()`, a excepción del mismo `Scanner.nextLine()`.

### Soluciones:

- Llamar al método `Scanner.nextLine()` después de haber llamado algún método `Scanner.next...()` para consumir ese carácter de salto de línea que quedó sin consumir.

  ```
  System.out.println("Enter student's grade: ");
  this.grade = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.nextLine(); // <----
  ```
- O, leer la entrada siempre con `Scanner.nextLine()` y convertir la `String` obtenida al formato que se necesite.

  ```
  System.out.println("Enter student's grade: ");
  String gradeStr = scanner.nextLine(); // <----
  this.grade = Integer.parseInt(gradeStr); // <----
  ```

Debes asegurarte de aplicar cualquiera de las soluciones en todos los casos en los que usaste `scanner.nextInt()` y `scanner.nextDouble()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que veo es que :
El atributo/Campo "**grade**" lo declaraste de tipo "**int**", por lo tanto al capturar el valor con la instancia de "**scanner**" deberías "parsear" el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
    this.grade = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

---

*Intenta y me cuentas.*

Comment: El método nextInt() de la clase Scanner ya devuelve de por sí un entero (int). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--

Comment: Ha funcionado correctamente, gracias. Pero no entiendo la linea de codigo de parseInt

Answer (score 0):

En mi codigo con la Clase Scanner, no tuve saltos de lineas con int o con double, pero si con long, aplique despues del long la solucion propuesta: scanner.nextLine() y se solucionó el inconveniente.
Observacion: Para este ejemplo, objeto de la Clase Scanner, se llama scanner, aun que parezca confuso, al objeto scanner, le puedes dar otro nombre: leer, read, etc.
Saludos y gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/395102)